# How to find/extract Page numbers from the text?

Tags: python, regex, ocr

I have been doing OCR on some images which are part of a different documents and they have Page numbers in the bottom.I have figured out a way to find each document but the images are not in sequence and I want  to sort them by their page numbers. One hiccups is that there are variations in the formats of the page numbers i.e

- `Page 1 of 35`
- `Page 1-35`
- `Page 35`

Plus the `Page` can be in lowercase `page` also. What i am looking for is a generic method using regex to extract this from the pages. It will be great if it can be handled in one regex as compiled version will be faster than having different ones for each case. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below regex,

```
page\s[\d]?[\s\d\-of]+
```

Use 'I' flag for case insensitive.

[RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/TEc4Hx/2)

Comment: it works good mate. but there are few cases which are not handled and are identified. ie."page 35 6663 24", "page 34 o", "page o f 2"

Comment: yes i did. what i am saying is these shouldn't be extracted. single number page numbers wont have space after it. as in "page 35 6663 24" this should have extracted "page 35", and two number page numbers ie. "page o f 2" should look for number first.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if the below commands is suited for you purpouse. Thanks

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w*\s\w*\d{1,5}','Page 1-35')
['Page 1']
>>> re.findall(r'\w*\s\w*\d{1,5}','Page 35')
['Page 35']
>>> re.findall(r'\w*\s\w*\d{1,5}','Page 1 of 35')[0]
'Page 1'
>>> re.findall(r'\w*\s\w*\d{1,5}','page 1 of 35')[0]
'page 1'
`
```